# Perl regexp partial replacement

Tags: regex, string, perl, replace

I want to replace all instances of a number in a string, but only if that number is the in the nth column where the columns are space-delimited.

This is what I had so far:

```
$_ =~ s/\s+([^\s]+\s+){$numcols}$i(.*)\n/$rep/;
```

Basically, there will be a few spaces, and then there will be: (non-spaces (column) followed by spaces) for $numcols times. Then, there will be $i, where $i is the number I want to replace,  followed by some characters I don't care about and a newline. However, I don't want to replace ALL OF THAT with $rep, but only $i. How do I do that?

Comment: I think it might be easier to split on space and replace the nth element of the resulting array.

Comment: Problem is I have to reprint it, and I don't know beforehand how many spaces I need to add in between each column

Comment: Please note that you don't need to specify `$_ =~`.  That is the default.  It's why `$_` exists.  `$_` is the "it" variable.  Just do `s/.../..../`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$_ =~ s/^(\s+(?:[^\s]+\s+){$numcols})$i/$1$rep/;
```

We're catching everything before `$i` as one group (with a non-capturing group denoted by `?:` in the middle of it). We're keeping all that, replacing just `$i`, and leaving the rest of the string alone.

Comment: Excellent, thanks. However, I have realized that I actually was doing something wrong. I need to replace EVERY instance in columns 0 through numcols of $i, with rep, whereas before I was just replacing the numcolsth instance. Also, just wondering, why does this work since ?: the noncapturing group does not act upon the first \s+?